# How to plot horizontal lines from a single point

Tags: gnuplot

I have a dataset(a file) with a single column and some entries. I wish to plot a horizontal line for each entry, where each entry is the y-axis value of the line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a strange plot you're trying to make.  You can do it using vectors without heads:

```
set style arrow 1 nohead
plot 'datafile' using (0.0):1:(0.0):(2.0) with vectors arrowstyle 1
```

Or, in gnuplot shorthand (just for fun):

```
p 'datafile' u (0.0):1:(0.0):(2.0) w vec as 1
```

*adjust `yrange` and `xrange` accordingly*